# Disabling git hub actions on Fridays for PROD Deployment

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, pipeline

I am pretty new to Git Hub actions. We have a requirement to disable release to PROD on Fridays and keep it enabled for the rest of the days.
Is there a way to achieve that in GitHub Actions(GHA).

Thanks!

Comment: I've found these in the [marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=weekend+): https://github.com/marketplace/actions/free-weekend https://github.com/marketplace/actions/no-weekend-merge https://github.com/marketplace/actions/breaktime-action

Answer (score 0):

You can [setup a Environment Protection Rule](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/protecting-deployments/configuring-custom-deployment-protection-rules#using-existing-custom-deployment-protection-rules) which will be called to check whether a release is allowed to proceed.

But it [requires setting up a custom GitHub App to block the deployments to the environment base don your own rules](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/protecting-deployments/configuring-custom-deployment-protection-rules#prerequisites).